# Angular-9: How to make login page as a defualt page in Angular-9?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular9

I have downloaded an open source tamplate of angular9 from a website. When I run the tamplate it shows the ***dashboard/default*** by default. **I want that it should run *auth/signin* by default** instead of ***dashboard/default***.

Routing structure that has already been defined by the auther of the template is following.
***app-routing.module.tc***

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AdminComponent } from './theme/layout/admin/admin.component';
import {AuthComponent} from './theme/layout/auth/auth.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdminComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'dashboard/default',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: () => import('./demo/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(module => module.DashboardModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'layout',
        loadChildren: () => import('./demo/pages/layout/layout.module').then(module => module.LayoutModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'basic',
        loadChildren: () => import('./demo/ui-elements/ui-basic/ui-basic.module').then(module => module.UiBasicModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'forms',
        loadChildren: () => import('./demo/pages/form-elements/form-elements.module').then(module => module.FormElementsModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'tbl-bootstrap',
        loadChildren: () => import('./demo/pages/tables/tbl-bootstrap/tbl-bootstrap.module').then(module => module.TblBootstrapModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'charts',
        loadChildren: () => import('./demo/pages/core-chart/core-chart.module').then(module => module.CoreChartModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'maps',
        loadChildren: () => import('./demo/pages/core-maps/core-maps.module').then(module => module.CoreMapsModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'sample-page',
        loadChildren: () => import('./demo/pages/sample-page/sample-page.module').then(module => module.SamplePageModule)
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: AuthComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'auth',
        loadChildren: () => import('./demo/pages/authentication/authentication.module').then(module => module.AuthenticationModule)
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a Guard that implements `CanActivate` for that:

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService) {}

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if (!this.authService.isAuthenticated) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth');
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

Then use this guard on the routes you want to protect:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdminComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'dashboard/default',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard] // <--- Your guard here
      }
...
```

[Check more about Angular guard on the Angular documentation.](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate)

Comment: No problem mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try replacing `redirectTo: 'dashboard/default'` with `redirectTo: 'auth/signin'`?

There are plenty of video tutorials on all sorts of basics on Angular (like routing, for this example). You're going to have a hard time if you're going to be creating questions for every small detail you can't get right.

What I'm going to say is not to make you feel bad, but I also suggest you invest time into learning how to properly use Google. As a developer, regardless of the technology, having the ability to abstractize and synthesize a problem is crucial to solving it.

Good luck in your quest!

Comment: Sure Sir! I will try my best next time